# ListView Adapter with Dictionary from xml

Tags: android

I want to set an adapter to a ListView where the ListView's items are a Dictionary. 
And for localization purposes, I would prefer that the items are defined in xml below the "values" folder.

At the moment, I use a simple list with strings, where the array is defined in \values\arrays.xml

But I don't want to use the index of the selected item in the list - if I sometimes change the order of the items I have to change all the code dependant on this implicit index. Using a defined key would be a lot easier.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use Dictionary. It's [obsolete](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary.html). I think you'd do better with an `ArrayList` of custom `Object`s or a `HashMap`. Then you can get this `Object` from your `Adapter`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              //adapter.getItem(position); - this is how you can acces the object
              //connected to the selected item from the list
              //Then you can easily access an id of this object (or from HashMap)

            }
});
```

EDIT: If you want to have a list in xml, you can always add an abstract xml file to your resources. These can be localized too. It would go like this:

```
<my_word>
    <id>123</id>
    <word>My word</word>
</my_word>
```

But it would involve XML parsing so it's not necessarily easier solution.

Comment: Thanks, that would be the first step. But I still need to store the objects in a localizable XML.

Comment: But why is that a problem? Generally you store them under the same names and a custom `Object` can access them by the name (R.string.my_word_in_bilion_languages) and they'll be localized properly

Comment: You're right, but for simplicity I would prefer to store the list as an array/dictionary in xml instead of single strings. But your approach is totally sufficient

Comment: Edited my answer to give you another option